# I am trying to find the slope of a polyline in autocad in a simpler way

Tags: autocad

My title pretty much says it all. I am trying to find the slope of a drawn polyline in a faster way than I am currently doing it. Right now I have to draw the line, check the distance in properties, than use the contours I have in the drawing to get my elevation, and than calculate slope off of that. This gets very dicey when dealing with very steep slopes due to the closeness of the contours. Thanks.

Comment: 2D (LW) Polyline or 3D Polyline? How do you envisage the 'simpler way' working? Have you tried the `DIST` command?

Comment: I am currently using a 2d polyline but am willing to use the other if it would work. that distance command you mentioned is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. If you post it as an answer I can mark it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the standard AutoCAD `DIST` command - no programming required. This will return the distance, angle, and delta X, Y, & Z.